# Definir que método não seja serializado

Tags: java, jax-rs

Possuo um serviço rest que devolve como resposta o objeto de uma classe que contém a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class LocalizacaoLinhaWrapper implements
        Serializable {

    ...

    private List<LocalizacaoLinha> linhasFavoritas;

    private List<LocalizacaoLinha> linhasNaoFavoritas;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return linhasNaoFavoritas.isEmpty() && linhasNaoFavoritas.isEmpty();
    }

    //Getters e setters
}
```

Utilizo o seguinte comando para devolver a resposta:

```
LocalizacaoLinhaWrapperDTO wrapper = service.minhaConsulta()//realizo a consulta    
Response.status(Status.OK).entity(localizacaoWrapper).build()
```

Quando faço a requisição a este serviço tudo é serializado de forma correta, contudo tenho um intruso chamado `empty` em meu **json**, que foi gerado por conta da existência do método `LocalizacaoLinhaWrapper.isEmpty()`.

**É possível definir que este método seja desprezado no momento da serialização? Se sim, como fazê-lo?**

Comment: @BrunoCésar, sim, o provider padrão. Fiz uma edição na pergunta.

Comment: Adicionei sim, mas não funcionou. Pertence ao pacote javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient?

Comment: Estou utilizando o JBoss7. Para ser mais exato JBoss 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestEasy é o *provider* JAX-RS no JBoss AS. Na versão `7.1.1.Final` do JBoss AS a versão do RestEasy é a `2.3.2.Final` (pode ser visto em `modules\org\jboss\resteasy`).

Em sua [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.3.Final/userguide/html_single/#JAXB_+_JSON_provider) é dito que o *provider* JSON padrão é o Jettison. Isto significa que ele deveria reagir à anotação JAXB `@XmlTransient` quando configurado na entidade *accessor type*, por exemplo, `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, e não serializar tais métodos/atributos anotados desta forma.

No entanto a documentação parece estar errada, como encontrado neste [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-801), mostrando que era um *bug* na documentação e que o *provider* usado na verdade é o do Jackson.

Assumindo que esteja usando um gerenciador de dependências como o [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), você pode fazer algo deste tipo:

- adicionar a seguinte dependência (aqui no caso do `maven`) ao seu projeto:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>

    <!-- a versão é 1.9.2 por que é a encontrada nos modules do JBoss -->
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

O escopo será `provided`, já que o JBoss já tem tal dependência em seus *modules*.

- anotar seu método `isEmpty()` com `@JsonIgnore`, ficando assim:

```java
@JsonIgnore
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return linhasNaoFavoritas.isEmpty() && linhasNaoFavoritas.isEmpty();
}
```

A solução acima é para o JBoss AS na versão citada, então pode não ter o mesmo comportamento em outros *containers* JEE.

Uma outra forma é criar seu próprio *provider* customizado, como pode ser visto [neste](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) exemplo. Neste caso você poderá usar o serializador que quiser para entregar JSON, e, por último, renomear seu método `isEmpty` para um nome que não é padrão *Java Beans*, como por exemplo renomeá-lo para algo como `hasFavorites`.

Caso precise, [neste](https://github.com/brunocesarsilva/jaxrs-example) repositório você poderá encontrar um exemplo completo usando a abordagem citada acima, com pequenas diferenças, mas que simulam exatamente seu problema.

Comment: Mesmo adicionando a anotação o problema persiste.

Comment: @GeisonSantos qual versão completa do jboss? Consegue disponibilizar um exemplo completo com o erro? Pode ser um *gist* mesmo, porque testei deste tipo nesta versão e funcionou ok

Comment: Jboss-as-7.1.1.Final. Não ocorre erro. O problema é que serializa o método. O que resulta no atributo `empty` no meu json.

Comment: @GeisonSantos erro foi só a forma de chamar o problema. Como disse, aqui ficou OK com essa abordagem, se conseguir gerar um *sample* de projeto para eu tentar reproduzir seu problema... Vice está usando configurações padrão, certo? Se tiver alterado alguma coisa, informe também.

Comment: Bruno, baixei e testei o projeto de exemplo do Github. Realmente funciona perfeitamente. O meu problema deve ser algo específico, alguma coisa relacionada a conflito de libs. Na verdade, nem existe mais o problema, pois removi os métodos, não eram tão importantes assim ;). Vou sinalizar sua resposta como correta. Obrigado pela atenção e parabéns por sua dedicação. Sua participação é muito importante para o SOpt.